# how can i use mySQL database connection using Cocos2d-JS

Tags: cocos2d-js

I'm new in cocos2d-JS and i don't have idea how
to connect mysql database 
using cocos2d-js.
 I searched on Google and forums but i can not find information.
please let me know how to connect.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the sample code.. Hope it would help to solve your problems..

Description: Code below are used to retrieve high score from MySQL using XMLHttpRequest, parse them to JSON and show them in the scene using ccui.ListView (don't forget to add 'extensions' module in your project.json file to include ccui modules or otherwise the ListView won't work..)

```
var HiScoreScene = cc.Scene.extend({
result: {},
ctor: function(){
    this._super();
    this.init();
},

init: function () {
    cc.log("Entering Select High Scores Scene");

    var winSize = cc.view.getDesignResolutionSize();
    var xhr = cc.loader.getXMLHttpRequest();
    var self = this;

    self.labelHighScores = new cc.LabelTTF("High Scores", "Comic Sans MS", 30);
    self.labelHighScores.setColor(cc.color(255,255,255));
    self.labelHighScores.x = winSize.width / 2;
    self.labelHighScores.y = winSize.height / 1.05;
    self.addChild(self.labelHighScores, 1);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            cc.log("Getting High Scores Details..");
            self.result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            var listView = new ccui.ListView();
            listView.setDirection(ccui.ScrollView.DIR_VERTICAL);
            listView.setGravity(ccui.ListView.GRAVITY_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            listView.setTouchEnabled(true);
            listView.setBounceEnabled(true);
            listView.setBackGroundImage(res.HiScoreBG_png);
            listView.setContentSize(cc.size(500, 600));
            listView.setAnchorPoint(cc.p(0.5, 0.5));
            listView.setPosition(cc.p(winSize.width / 2, winSize.height / 2));
            self.addChild(listView);


            for (var i = 0; i < self.result.length ; i++) {
                var button = new ccui.Button();
                var button2 = new ccui.Button();
                var button3 = new ccui.Button();
                var button4 = new ccui.Button();
                var button5 = new ccui.Button();
                var button6 = new ccui.Button();

                //Set Player Name
                button.setName("PlayerName");
                button.setTouchEnabled(false);
                button.setTitleColor(cc.color.BLACK);
                button.setTitleFontName("Comic Sans MS");
                button.setTitleFontSize(25);
                button.setTitleText("Player Name : " + self.result[i].player_name);

                //Set Easy High Score
                button2.setName("EasyHighScore");
                button2.setTouchEnabled(false);
                button2.setTitleColor(cc.color.BLACK);
                button2.setTitleFontName("Comic Sans MS");
                button2.setTitleFontSize(25);
                button2.setTitleText("Easy : " + self.result[i].easy_hiscore);

                //Set Medium High Score
                button3.setName("MedHighScore");
                button3.setTouchEnabled(false);
                button3.setTitleColor(cc.color.BLACK);
                button3.setTitleFontName("Comic Sans MS");
                button3.setTitleFontSize(25);
                button3.setTitleText("Medium : " + self.result[i].med_hiscore);

                //Set Hard High Score
                button4.setName("HardHighScore");
                button4.setTouchEnabled(false);
                button4.setTitleColor(cc.color.BLACK);
                button4.setTitleFontName("Comic Sans MS");
                button4.setTitleFontSize(25);
                button4.setTitleText("Hard : " + self.result[i].hard_hiscore);

                //Set GodLike High Score
                button5.setName("GodHighScore");
                button5.setTouchEnabled(false);
                button5.setTitleColor(cc.color.BLACK);
                button5.setTitleFontName("Comic Sans MS");
                button5.setTitleFontSize(25);
                button5.setTitleText("GodLike : " + self.result[i].god_hiscore);

                button6.setName("Space");
                button6.setTouchEnabled(false);
                button6.setTitleColor(cc.color.BLACK);
                button6.setTitleFontName("Comic Sans MS");
                button6.setTitleFontSize(25);
                button6.setTitleText(" ");

                listView.pushBackCustomItem(button);
                listView.pushBackCustomItem(button2);
                listView.pushBackCustomItem(button3);
                listView.pushBackCustomItem(button4);
                listView.pushBackCustomItem(button5);
                listView.pushBackCustomItem(button6);
            }

        }
        else if(xhr.status == 403){
            cc.log("Access Forbidden !!");
        }
        else if(xhr.status == 404){
            cc.log("File Not Found !!");
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "php/getHighScore.php", true);
    xhr.send();

    self.optionMenuItem1 = new cc.MenuItemFont("Back To Main Menu", mainMenu);
    self.optionMenuItem1.setFontName("Comic Sans MS");
    self.optionMenuItem1.setFontSize(25);

    self.menu = new cc.Menu(self.optionMenuItem1);
    self.menu.setPosition(winSize.width / 2, winSize.height / 22);
    self.addChild(self.menu, 1);

    return true;
}});
```

For more explanation you might want to check them out [here](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/load-json-parse-result-from-xmlhttprequest-into-the-scene/29676/4)

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d-JS is javascript so, It's like javascript, if you wanna pass value into MySQL Database, use ajax request [example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)